# Angular Forms with string values and *ngIf

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to not display forms in a list if they are empty. The form's values are string. I tried to use *ngIf but, it didn't work and I can still see empty places in the list. How can I solve this? (In the image, ISRawMaterialInspection and ISRawMaterialRiskState are the ones that are empty.)

Here is the HTML:

```
<input matInput class="mt-20" formControlName="IsOxidizable" *ngIf="form.get('IsOxidizable').value"/>

    <input matInput class="mt-20" formControlName="ISRawMaterialInspection" *ngIf="!!form.get('ISRawMaterialInspection').value"/>
                        
    <input matInput class="mt-20" formControlName="ISRawMaterialRiskState" *ngIf="form.get('ISRawMaterialRiskState').value"/>
```

Here is the TS:

```
        IsOxidizable: new FormControl({
            value: this.data.IsOxidizable,
            disabled: true,
        }),
       
        ISRawMaterialRiskState: new FormControl({
            value: this.data.ISRawMaterialRiskState,
            disabled: true,
        }),
        ISRawMaterialInspection: new FormControl({
            value: this.data.ISRawMaterialInspection,
            disabled: true
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try checking on the control and not the control value? form.get('ISRawMaterialRiskState')

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work

Comment: Can you share the full html with `<form` tag and also the ts part?

Comment: See this stackblitz for example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nfrp-shared-changes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
Are you values from your service coming back as null or empty strings? If null you would be fine otherwise your check would be on !== ''

Comment: No, they don't come back as null. They are always coming back with their title. (Oksitlenme for example). That can be the problem I guess?

Comment: If you could paste your full html / ts that would be helpful. If you're always getting a value back from your service then your ngIf would always be true thus always displaying and irrelevant.

Comment: @RocketMonkey, why the two `!!` ? use a simple `!` to indicate is null, false or ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some comment Input from **Eliseo** my previous answer needed some edit.

As Eliseo stated

> if(a) condition in typescript is false if a is equal to undefined,
> null, "",0 or false

```
    <input matInput class="mt-20" formControlName="IsOxidizable" *ngIf="form.get('IsOxidizable').value && form.get('IsOxidizable').value !== ''"/>

    <input matInput class="mt-20" formControlName="ISRawMaterialInspection" *ngIf="form.get('ISRawMaterialInspection').value form.get('IsOxidizable').value !== ''"/>
                        
    <input matInput class="mt-20" formControlName="ISRawMaterialRiskState" *ngIf="form.get('ISRawMaterialRiskState').value form.get('IsOxidizable').value !== ''"/>
```

But considering that OP has accepted the answer and probably solved the problem, there is a catch here.

```
var a = new String('');

if (a) -> will evaluate to true
```

So maybe OP didn't use primitive string, but String objects.

> if(a) condition in typescript is false if a is equal to undefined,
> null, "",0 or false **only for primitive data types**.

```
if (new Boolean(false)) -> evaluates to true
if (new String('')) -> evaluates to true
if (new Number(0)) -> evaluates to true
```

In the end thanks Eliseo for clarification which helped me get better.

Comment: @Eliseo you were right. I have removed my comments to not make OPs more frustrated and edited my answer with your help.

Comment: sorry I'm so picky sometimes, but if a=0, b=false and c="", if(a) is evaluated as false, if(b) is evaluate as false and if(c) is also evaluate as false. When you write `if (new Boolean(false))` give true because is an "object" in the way [Boolean:false] (yes is an strange object) -the same happens with new Number(0) and new String('')-

Answer (score 0):

Changing HTML and using

```
 <input matInput class="mt-20" formControlName="IsOxidizable" *ngIf="form.get('IsOxidizable').value && form.get('IsOxidizable').value !== ''"/>
```

worked. After that, I also changed the main TS without adding `form.get('IsOxidizable').value !== ''` to the HTML code. Since, it would always come back with its title, I edited the main TS like below:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (this.rawMaterialInformation) {
                this.rawMaterialInformation.IsOxidizable = this.rawMaterialInformation.IsOxidizable?
                    "Oksitlenme :" + this.rawMaterialInformation.IsOxidizable:'';

                this.rawMaterialInformation.MeltingTemperature = this.rawMaterialInformation.MeltingTemperature?
                    "Eritilme Sıcaklığı : " +
                    this.rawMaterialInformation.MeltingTemperature:'';
```

}

It works both ways.

Comment: Nop Rocket, if value, value!==''